# QtJambi 4.6.3.2 windows 7

Tags: java, windows-7, java-native-interface, qt-jambi

I wrote a simple app using QtJambi in particular the `com.trolltech.qt.webkit.QWebView` class.
On linux everything works fine, but when I run the Win32 version I got

```
   at com.trolltech.qt.internal.NativeLibraryManager.loadNativeLibrary(NativeLibraryManager.java:431)
   at com.trolltech.qt.internal.NativeLibraryManager.loadQtLibrary(NativeLibraryManager.java:355)
   at com.trolltech.qt.Utilities.loadQtLibrary(Utilities.java:145)
   at com.trolltech.qt.Utilities.loadQtLibrary(Utilities.java:141)
   at com.trolltech.qt.webkit.QtJambi_LibraryInitializer.<clinit>(QtJambi_LibraryInitializer.java:10)
   ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\polettid\AppData\Local\Temp\QtJambi_polettid_x86_4.6.3_msvc2005-20100709-1245\bin\QtWebKit4.dll: The specified procedu
       at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.Runtime.load(Unknown Source)
       at com.trolltech.qt.internal.NativeLibraryManager.loadLibrary_helper(NativeLibraryManager.java:458)
       at com.trolltech.qt.internal.NativeLibraryManager.loadNativeLibrary(NativeLibraryManager.java:426)
       ... 8 more
```

Can someone suggest some solution, the only help I found is on an old [post](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.qt.jambi/2189) but the problem seems different.

I build the package using maven with the qtjambi plugin:

```
             <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.sf.qtjambi</groupId>
            <artifactId>qtjambi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.3.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>qtjambi</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
```

Comment: Maybe you could try more recent build, for MSVC at http://www.labstory.se/compiledqt/ ?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

I downloaded the window package from http://qt-jambi.org/downloads and unzip it.
Then I add to the PATH environment variable the `lib` directory inside the unpackaged zip that contains the ddls.

Everything works now.